# Can Microsoft Word add-in developed in office.js support Mobile Word app ? (I knew outlook add-ins has support for mobile)

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

we are working on making Microsoft word add-in using office.js and other additional technologies.

As we are looking for generic project, i have query whether is there way / does Word Add-ins supports in Mobile Microsoft word app (Android/Mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office JS add-in is cross-platform support. Office Add-ins run in:

- Office on the web
- Windows
- Mac
- iPad

Unfortunately we currently do not support android platform.
for more information, you could refer to this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins

Comment: Thanks Raymond for quick reply.

Comment: Let me know if you successfully get this to work TempMail Ms. I tried side loading my excel add in last night to my iPad and was getting errors.